# Nullify an index of a struct array in C without overwriting values pointed to by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, process

This code has been simplified from the actual version in order to make it easier to read, the actual code includes a lot of header files and is massive.

I have an array of structs (processes) and I have a pointer Current as defined below. I want to remove from the array one proc:

```
typedef struct proc proc;
typedef stuct proc *procPtr;

struct proc{
   procPtr nextProc;
   procPtr parentProc;
   procPtr deadChildren;
   char *name;
   int pid;
};

int slot = 0 // the slot to operate on in the table
proc ProcTable[MAX];
procPtr Current;
proc null;

null.nextProc = NULL;
null.parentProc = NULL;
null.deadChildren = NULL;
strcpy(null.name, "Nil");
null.pid = -1;

/*Some code, table is populated with null procPtr*/

strcpy(ProcTable[slot].name, "Proc2");
ProcTable[slot].nextProc = NULL;
ProcTable[slot].deadChildren = NULL;
ProcTable[slot].parentProc = Current;
ProcTable[slot].pid = 2;

/* Some code, Current proc is switched to child and quitting*/
Current = &ProcTable[slot];

/* Remove the process from the table */
Current->parentProc->deadChildren = Current;
ProcTable[slot] = null;

printf("Process removed: Current points to %s,
       ProcTable value: %s", Current->name, ProcTable[slot].name);

return;
```

This is the return:

```
>Process removed: Current points to Nil, ProcTable value: Nil
```

What I understand is the pointer Current is pointing to the value in the ProcTable, but the values are being changed when I try to "remove" the process from the table, the values are being overwritten. This is an issue because I'm not saving the data of the dead child processes in its parents list then.

How do I resolve this? How can I "remove" the process from the array without overwriting the data Current is being pointed to?

Comment: A `struct` cannot be a process in C. Note: do not `typedef` pointers. This obfuscates their semantcs and results in less readable/maintainable code, is error-prone and is harder to use.Instead use explict pointers for your code.

Comment: where do you think does `null.name` point in the line `strcpy(null.name, "Nil");`?

Comment: The typedefs were given. I'm not changing those for syntax purposes.

Comment: At the top, did you mean to put typedef struct proc *proc... You put "stuct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but I will try to answer.

First, you have an error in your code:

`strcpy(null.name, "Nil");`

No memory is allocated for null.name, so this will cause an error (if you are lucky enough).

What I understand you are trying to do, is keep the removed process' info within its parent's dead children, when the child is "removed".

I would suggest using a list, as obviously the array is used for the "active" processes. You cannot just point to the array, because any changes you make to it are reflected to the pointers pointing to it.

Then you could move list nodes among the active processes list, the the dead children of a process, etc.

Even if no other process will ever be "written" in a position of the array after a process has been "removed", you cannot maintain the deadChildren chain with just one array.

I hope this helps. If not, please indicate further problems.

Comment: I'm not returning any problems on valgrind, I'm using a simulator for an Operating System, so maybe it's handling the allocation for me

Comment: I'm not quite following this. deadChildren is a list, the point from a process would be a parent pointing to the head of a list of its dead child processes, so I already have a list.

I just want to remove the process from the table without changing the process values.

Comment: How is deadChildren a list? If you are using the deadChildren pointer as the "next" dead child pointer of the "list", then you have messed up your program semantics.

Comment: it points to the head of the list of dead child processes. This is how we were told to do it. I'm just trying to find out how to remove a process from an array index

Comment: Anyway, I see what you are doing. You have to allocate space for the new process and copy the process you want to remove, then delete it (nullify) from the array. That's really ugly C code by the way (not blaming you).

Comment: To be fair, operating systems are ugly haha

Answer (score 0):

`ProcTable` is an array of `procs`, so when you do this:

```
Current->parentProc->deadChildren = Current;
ProcTable[slot] = null;
```

You are *copying* the `null` struct *into* `ProcTable[slot]` overwriting the old `Current` which also overwrites `Current->parentProc->deadChildren` because it's pointing to the same thing.

EDIT:
I think I understand now. This must be a homework assignment. You are expected to use the array as a memory pool so as not to have to use dynamic memory allocation. But you need to still used a linked list structure. In that case, when you need to 'remove' a proc and make it a child, just re-jigger the pointers, but don't remove from the array.

Comment: deadChildren is a linked list. The first child would be the head

Comment: Then why are you mixing arrays and linked lists? I suggest changing `ProcTable` to a `proc *` and abandon the array entirely. You would then need to allocate (using `malloc`) a new `proc` each time one is created. Then when you set `deadChildren` you won't have an issue.

Comment: The array is given. It is an array of fixed size 50. The array is so I can remove processes that are executed to make room for new ones, the list is to keep a reference to all child processes of a parent that are executed as that list can be more than 50 processes